# Xcode 6: Adding Existing Classes Produce Compilation Error

Tags: ios, xcode6

I've just installed *Xcode 6* and I've found that .. whenever I try to add an existing file to the project it produce a compilation error in the basic `UIKit` classes such as `UITableView` and `NSObject` ..

[image]

I have no idea why this is happening!

Comment: Which imports do you use

Comment: Is #import<UIKit/UIKit.h> line in your .pch ?

Answer (score 0):

as per Shai and iDev answers i found that in xcode 6 there's no default PCH file .. so there's no default import for uikit and foundation .. it should be added manually .